# Parsing html partial templates using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to parse html templates using lxml and adding certain attributes to html elements.  I can do so successfuly but when reading a document via

```
 template = etree.parse(view, etree.HTMLParser(remove_comments=True))
```

and then saving the document. I noticed that my templates contain additional markup to make it a valid html template. Wrapping a template like

```
 <div>
   <span> A template </span>
 </div>
```

with html and body tags, turning it into something like

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <div>
   <span> A template </span>
 </div>
 </body>
 <html>
```

How do I read my 'broken' html templates and prevent lxml from adding these additional tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply dont use html parser

with html parser:

```
>>> template = etree.fromstring('<div><span> A template </span></div>', etree.HTMLParser(remove_comments=True))
>>> etree.tostring(template)
'<html><body><div><span> A template </span></div></body></html>'
```

without it:

```
>>> template = etree.fromstring('<div><span> A template </span></div>')
>>> etree.tostring(template)
'<div><span> A template </span></div>'
```